# How to change colour of outline after I draw with a brush in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, brush

I drew something in Photoshop using brushes but I wanted to change the outline colour. I have seen many people change the outline colour without any side effect like became thicker. I tried to use the paint bucket tool and the colour change according to what I wanted but it became thicker.

Please can someone explain how to change outline colour

I don't want to change the fill colour, just the stroke/outline.

Comment: A tad bit confused since **brushes** simply can not create a shape with a stroke. They create a single element with one color. The *only* color variations possible via brushes are things like the color dynamics and hue shifting, but that won't ever add a "stroke" to  brush artwork.

Answer (score 3):

I think, You can give layer style stroke.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are not well familiar with everyday pro features such as adjustment layers and masks. I assume the most obvious case: You have painted onto a white background in the background layer itself, not created a new layer for the painting

If you have only black on white, you can colorize it with Image > Adjustments > Hue&Saturation, colorize crossed

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

The white background is not affected, if you have positive (+) Lightness.

A little more complex is the case where the lines are already colored and have different colors:

[image]

Let's assume you want to change green to blue. You can make selective color shift. Now only green is affected. The affected range can be adjusted with the sliders at the bottom:

[image]

Try it, but press cancel, because now it's the right place to take a step to pro methods and do this non-destructively.

Goto Layer > New Adjustment layer > Hue&Saturation

[image]

The new layer affects to the underlying image. The readjustment is possible with no side-effects. Only double-click the round half black-half white icon in the Layers panel to make the sliders available, if they have vanished because you have tried something else.

The white rectangle refers to the layer mask which is very useful if you want disable the layer on part of the image. There white=enable, black = disable.

Recommendations:

- Draw new shapes to new layers
- Learn to use adjustment layers and layer masks.

Note that my samples are from a legacy Photoshop. Modern versions have much more flexibility. That means also more controls to select from.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the type of your draw 
- Create a new Layer 
- Draw on it
- Change the type of your layer to "Dynamic or Pixelized"
- Double click on the layer -> in properties apply the outfit and change the colors and size.